# Event Propagation in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal. If I click on the background, I want the modal to go away. If I click on the modal form, I do not want it to go away. Having an issue where trigger events on the form are bubbling up to the container background and closing the div. I want the modal to NOT close if the inner div is clicked.

(clearQuiz makes the modal disappear)

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import { clearQuiz } from '../../actions/quiz'; 
import './Quiz.css'; 

export class Quiz extends React.Component {

    handleClose(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.props.dispatch(clearQuiz()); 
    }


    render() {  

        let answers = this.props.answers.map((answer, idx) => (
            <li key={idx}>{answer}</li>
        )); 

        if (this.props.usingQuiz) {
            return ( 
                <div className="quiz-backdrop" onClick={e => this.handleClose(e)}>
                    <div className="quiz-main">
                        <h2>{this.props.title} Quiz</h2>
                        <h3>{this.props.currentQuestion}</h3>
                        <ul>
                        {answers}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )  
        } 
        else {
            return <Redirect to="/" />; 
        }      
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    usingQuiz: state.currentQuestion, 
    answers: state.answers, 
    currentQuestion: state.currentQuestion, 
    title: state.currentQuiz, 

}); 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Quiz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the event at all! Try `onClick={()=>this.handleClose()}`.

Comment: So I did this, and I get this error: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined

Comment: it can't identify what e is in the method

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Remove the parameter e and e.stopPropagation() from handleClose() as well.

Comment: The clearQuiz function definitely works. I have the method like this now:

Comment: handleClose() {
        
        this.props.dispatch(clearQuiz()); 
    }

Comment: now it's throwing this error: 'cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.'

Comment: The clearQuiz function works whether I want it to or not ha. I'm trying to make sure it stops working.

Comment: Last try - don't make the quiz a child of the background. Make them siblings in the DOM.